# how can i used other function instead of each() function is deprecated?

Tags: php, for-loop, each

here I share my old code need with each function so now I got this kind of error

```
each() function is deprecated
```

my code is

```
list($k, $v) = each($files);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` statement like :

```
<?php

foreach($files as $k => $v) {
    // Do some stuffs
}
```

`Foreach` works since PHP 4.

Comment: how can i change this each function in new PHP code

$('.selected', window.parent.document).each(function () {